# ArcGIS 10 and IGeometryServer2

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

Has anyone already used IGeometryServer2 or IGeometryServer within C# code? I'm looking for a sample since I have not succeeded in using it.

I have already selected:
One Polyline (IPolyline) : for cutting
One Polyline (IGeometry) : the shape to be cut

Comment: It looks like you asked it here so I will link your question from the ESRI forums http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/35480-C-sample-with-IGeometryServer2.cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of IGeometryServer usage: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISEngine/arcobjects/esriGeometry/esriGeometry_GeometryServer_example.htm

Comment: That's from ArcGIS Server 9.3 he wanted samples from 10.0.

Comment: Didn't read the post title closely.

Answer (score 1):

Esri's website seems to have everything you need. Here is the [API Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Cut_Method/002m000001z2000000/) for the [IGeometryServer2.Cut](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Cut_Method/002m000001z2000000/)  Method. They also have a whole section on [migrating your code from 9.3 to 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Migrating_your_code/000100000m62000000/) that also may be of use to you. The site also has the [sample code](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Geometry_service/000100000414000000/) of the GeometryServer with 10.0 that you requested.